# Find the index of each 100, 10, -10, 20, -20, and 11 (mod 101)

Tags: number-theory

If we know that 2 is a primitive root mod 101, how can we get the index (discrete logarithm) of each 100, 10, -10, 20, -20, and 11 ?

Comment: What have you tried?  To get started, it is pretty easy to read off the index of $100$.

Comment: @lulu well the thing is, I don't know how to start. There is a theorem about if you know the index of n^2 then you only have two choices for the index of n

Comment: Well, since $2^{100}=1$, we must have $2^{50}=\pm 1$.  Since it can't be $+1$....

Comment: @lulu ohh okay then I can get the index of 10 and -10 from this?

Comment: That hint gives the index of $100$.  To get the index of $\pm 10$ use the facts that a). $2^{25}$ is a fourth root of $1$ and b) $10^2=-1$.  $\pm 20$ follow easily (since  $2^a=10\implies 2^{a+1}=20$).  I don't see a fast way to get the index of $11$.  Trial and error isn't too bad, but there's probably a clever way.

Comment: @lulu this is a challenge: Find the index of 17 in Z/101Z where 2 is a primitive root. Do you have any idea how to think about this?

Comment: Other than trial and error, no.  That's pretty easy though!  Remember, as you are doing multiplications mod (101) you don't have much to compute.  There may well be a clever trick for it, but finding that trick is probably harder than trial and error (in excel, or anything else,  it takes just a few seconds to get all the powers of $2$ mod (101) )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30790/discussion-between-kevin-and-lulu).